Systematical numbers
What word is hidden below?

[5] [10][ ]
[ ] [3] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]
[9] [2] [ ]
[4] [6] [ ]
[1] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ]
[7] [ ] [ ]
    [ ] [8]


(It's slightly misspelled, but you'll see what I mean)
Hint 1a

 The "missing one" is important. What could it mean?

Hint 1b

 They're all in relation to it.


The answer is

 COORDINATES which is slightly misspelt in the puzzle as CORDINATES

Reason

 First we have to interpret the ‘missing one’ in the bottom left as 0,0.

Then

 We take the coordinates of the numbers in numerical order in the boxes in relation to that: (0,3)(1,5)(1,8)(0,4)(0,9)(1,4)(0,1)(2,0)(0,5)(1,9).

Next

 We then index the letters from the coordinates using the A1Z26 cipher in order of the numbers and you get CORDINATES.


That's the answer, well done!
